How to fix Flutter dependencies for web build
i can't build a flutter app for the web , i got problems about dependencies , i tried to upgrade flutter but it didn't work so i downgrade it back to it's original version.
here is my pubspec.yaml
                environment:
                  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

                dependencies:
                  abg_utils: 8.0.8
                  html_editor_enhanced: 2.5.1
                  timeago: ^3.1.0
                  maps_toolkit: ^2.0.0
                  google_maps_flutter_web: 0.3.2+1
                  google_maps_flutter: 2.1.1
                  universal_html: 2.0.8
                  soundpool: 2.2.0
                  provider: 6.0.2
                  image_picker: 0.8.4+7
                  syncfusion_flutter_charts: 19.2.62

                  flutter:
                    sdk: flutter

                  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
                  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2


                dependency_overrides:
                  ffi: ^2.0.1
                  win32: ^3.0.0


                dev_dependencies:
                  flutter_test:
                    sdk: flutter

                flutter:

                  uses-material-design: true

                  assets:
                    - assets/
                    - assets/dashboard2/
                    - assets/fonts/
                    - assets/ondemands/
                    - assets/elements/


                  fonts:
                    - family: Montserrat
                      fonts:
                        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
                          weight: 400
                        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
                          weight: 600
                        - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf
                          weight: 800
                    - family: Harmattan # arabic
                      fonts:
                        - asset: assets/fonts/Harmattan-Regular.ttf
                          weight: 400
                        - asset: assets/fonts/Harmattan-Bold.ttf
                          weight: 800

                    - family: NunitoSans
                      fonts:
                        - asset: assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf
                          weight: 400
                        - asset: assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf
                          weight: 600
                        - asset: assets/fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf
                          weight: 800

and when i run this command flutter build web i got those errors and warning
                  Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:2:1:
              Error: Error when reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': Error reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'  (No such
              file or directory)
              export 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions;
              ^
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:6:8:
              Error: Error when reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': Error reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart'  (No such
              file or directory)
              import 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' as internals;
                     ^
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25:
              Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
                  FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/abg_utils-8.0.8/lib/src/ui/parent_screen.dart:31:22:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                   ^
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/abg_utils-8.0.8/lib/src/ui/scroller_resizer.dart:64:22:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                   ^
              ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/abg_utils-8.0.8/lib/src/ui/dialogs/easy_dialog_2.dart:138:38:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                                    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                                   ^
              lib/ui/payouts.dart:38:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/product/product.dart:36:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/product/product.dart:214:34:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                                WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                               ^
              lib/ui/product/product.dart:265:24:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                     ^
              lib/ui/providers/providers_request.dart:40:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/review.dart:23:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/settings/admin_panel_app_settings.dart:23:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/settings/provider_app_settings.dart:23:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/settings/website_app_settings.dart:24:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/subscription.dart:50:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/subscription.dart:209:32:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                              WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                             ^
              lib/ui/banners/banners.dart:36:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^
              lib/ui/banners/banners.dart:116:30:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                           ^
              lib/ui/blog/blog.dart:40:20:
              Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
               - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                                 ^

PS : i have to use an old flutter version to not break the code , this is my actual version of flutter and dart :
        flutter --version
    Flutter 3.7.0 • channel unknown • unknown source
    Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (1 year, 5 months ago) • 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
    Engine • revision b24591ed32
    Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1

i tried to change many dependencies version but i can't fix it , any idea how to fix this problem.

Errors you get are not dependencies errors. Dependencies error may appear when you execure flutter pub get command.
Your errors came principally from your source code and from package source code.
One of your package abg_utils does not seem's to be null safety friendly and your code too.
I don't know what you are trying to do with this code and where it come from, but if it was mine, first i will upgrade Flutter SDk, then dependencies and after all i will fix source code errors.
